# How to fit a smooth polynomial?

Tags: regularization, curve-fitting, smoothing

We have $N$ samples of the unknown function $f(x)$ on the finite interval $[a, b]$. The samples are subject to white noise of known variance. We want to approximate the function $f(x)$ by a polynomial $P_m(x)$ of order $m$. It is, however, known, that the original function $f(x)$  is smooth in some sense. For example, let's say we know that the original $f(x)$ is [Lipshitz-continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) on the interval $[a, b]$ with some known constant $K$. Is there a standard procedure to select the best-fitting polynomial $P_m(x)$ while requiring that the polynomial satisfies the smoothness requirement.

I am not bound to Lipshitz continuity. I am happy to switch to another metric of smoothness if it is more convenient for this problem. However, the smoothness metric should be minimax. This means that the bound must apply to the smoothness of the worst point of the function, which is not necessarily the average such as L2.

**EDIT**: Now also posted on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853622/how-to-fit-a-smooth-polynomial)

Comment: What do you mean by "best-fitting"? Minimal square errors subject to a given Lipshitz constant $K$?

Comment: @StephanKolassa yes

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to find a polynomial $P$ of degree $m$ that minimizes $\sum_i\big(P(x_i)-y_i\big)^2$, subject to $\big|\frac{P(x)-P(y)}{x-y}\big|\leq K$ for all $x\neq y\in[a,b]$. This sounds like a straightforward math question. It may just boil down to getting a handle on $\max_{x\neq y}\big|\frac{P(x)-P(y)}{x-y}\big|$, and shouldn't that just be $\max_x\big|P(x)\big|$? I think you may have a better chance of getting answers at Math.SE.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for advice. I was not sure if this is a very common problem or not. If it happened to be common, I was expecting that people on this forum would just tell me the name of the optimization function to use. But from your answer I conclude that it is not as common as I thought. I'll try the math forum as you suggest

Comment: Why not just impose the smoothness condition on the derivative of $P$?  That would be solved with a linearly constrained quadratic program.  Efficient, scalable implementations abound.

Comment: Are you married to using a polynomial? There are established procedures for imposing Lipschitz continuity on neural networks (important in differential privacy and so getting some attention). See, e.g. https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2018/file/d54e99a6c03704e95e6965532dec148b-Paper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

1. Define all your restrictions, such as Lipshitz continuity, degree of the polynomial etc.
2. Define a loss function for smoothness, e.g. in terms of second order derivative over the interval $\int_a^b f''(x)^2$ or otherwise $\max_{x \in [a,b]} f''(x)^2$.
3. Estimate the parameters of the polynomial by minimising this loss function.

Comment: Yes, so far everything is trivial. The question is what is the standard procedure for performing this minimization. How do we calcluate $\max_{x \in [a,b]} f''(x)^2$? Naively we would find the maximum of the 2nd derivative at every iteration, but that's probably too wasteful? Are there standard packages that support this kind of optimization? I would not want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: If you model $f(x)$ through a polynomial then finding this maximum is simply optimising the absolute value of another polynomial.

Comment: Can you please address the outlined concerns: how to optimally solve this problem? Has it been done before? Is there an existing algorithm that does it?

Comment: This exact formulation probably not, but optimising any function was, e.g. optim() in R

Comment: @Knarpie it's not immediately obvious to me that off-the-shelf "general purpose" optimizers like $\texttt{optim}$ can handle this problem: when using the absolute value formulation, it is not differentiable, when using a minimax formulation, we have a minimax game rather than straightforward optimization (maximization over high degree polynomials is not closed form), and do we know that this problem is convex in the polynomial coefficients?